# How To Play .any custom video file such as asf ,ts,mov etc in html pages using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, video-streaming, html5-video

Please give me the **steps** to do that.
If any **external plugins are required please state it** in the answer.
It would be glad if you can give **detail explanation** as I am just beginner in embedding video files in html pages and want to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible. Some formats can be transmuxed to a fragmented mp4 container on the fly via JavaScript. However they would still need to be the correct codecs.

If you need a detailed explanation, I recommend the book “video demystified”